# How many $5$-digit numbers can be made out of the digits $1, 2, 2, 2, 3$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $5$-digit numbers can be made out of the digits $1, 2, 2, 2, 3$ ?

I know it might be a basic question, but I do not remember how I used to solve these kinds of questions.

Comment: Arrange $5$ things, divide out the repetitions.

Comment: 120 matey just 5 factorial

Comment: Count the number of ways to choose $3$ of the $5$ positions to be filled by the twos, then multiply by the number of ways to fill the remaining $2$ positions with the $1$ and the $3$.

Comment: @hwood87 The answer is not $5!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to arrange 5 digits, some repeating, so for the sake of this question lets label each digit as 
$$1_1,2_1,2_2,2_3,3_1$$

Arranging 5 unique digits in different ways yields $5!$ results, or $5*4*3*2*1$.
However we have 3 digits which are not unique.

For example, the arrangements $2_1,1_1,2_2,2_3,3_1$ and $2_3,1_1,2_1,2_2,3_1$ yield the same 5-digit number $21223$. In order to solve this question we must remove the number of permutations of the duplicated digits. In this case, we have $3$ different $2$ digits, and the ways these can be permuted is $3!$ or $3*2*1$.

Therefore, the solution to this question is
$$\frac{5!}{3!}$$
$$=\frac{5*4*3*2*1}{3*2*1}$$
$$=5*4=20$$

This is similar to the popular "Mississippi" problem found here https://medium.com/i-math/can-you-solve-the-mississippi-problem-6c0f3b02531. This might be more helpful in understanding the reasoning in this method of solving.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay that explains everything now for where I was confused, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways in which $5$ things can be arranged $=5!=120$ ways.

However, we have the digit $2$ repeated $3$ times, so the twos can be permuted in $3!=6$ ways.

Therefore, the number of ways in which the given digits can form $5$ digit numbers is $\frac{120}{6}=20$ ways.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @KirlosY. You are welcome, such a pleasure if one finds my answer useful. I just like to suggest you to read similar questions in MSE, they maybe useful. :-)